# Getting CPU temperature

Tags: c#, cpu, temperature

I am building my own PC-Fan-Controller.   I am looking for a way to read the CPU temperature in C#. As there is no .NET-way to do this, I was reading through several topics and there people came up with things like the RMI-modules or ACPI or the Open Hardware Monitor and its dll.

Sadly I do not really have an idea how to realize this with RMI or one of the other methods. Is there anybody how could provide an command-line program-sample of how to read the cpu-temperature? Any other help is, of course, very nice.

Comment: Use WMI commands  - like SQL

Comment: https://www.google.com.au/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=reading%20cpu%20%2C%20wmi

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. In the current state your question is way too broad and is likely to get closed. Please read [help/on-topic] and [ask] for specific problems.

Comment: Check this WMI-class: Win32_PerfFormattedData_Counters_ThermalZoneInformation